# react-native-youtube library invariation error when adding library to react-native application

Tags: android, react-native, android-youtube-api, expo

I'm creating a movie and tv shows project with React Native and trying to add trailers video for each from YouTube but I'm getting this error.

```
Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "ReactYouTube" was not found in the UIManager.
```

This is what I'm currently doing : [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z471i.jpg)

```
import YouTube from 'react-native-youtube';

...

state = {
   isReady: false,
    status: "",
    quality: "",
    error: ""
}

...

          <YouTube
            apiKey="AIzaSyCce0TNBZDyCCP62B2P8EkTfgjgp20ZqOA"
            videoId="jKCj3XuPG8M" // The YouTube video ID
            play // control playback of video with true/false
            fullscreen={false} // video should play in fullscreen or inline
            loop={false} // control whether the video should loop when ended
            onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
            onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
            onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
            onError={e => this.setState({ error: e.error })}
            style={{ alignSelf: "stretch", height: 300 }}
          />
```

I've tried adding the ReactNativeYoutube package directly in the `MainApplication.java`

```
import com.inprogress.reactnativeyoutube.ReactNativeYouTube;

...

packages.add(new ModuleRegistryAdapter(mModuleRegistryProvider));
```

to the `settings.gradle`

```
include ':react-native-youtube'

project(':react-native-youtube').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-youtube/android')
```

and also to the `build.gradle`

```
implementation project(':react-native-youtube')
```

But I'm still getting the same error, Wondering if anyone has come across this same error and has a solution

Comment: If you only want to run on Android you only need to remove `"postinstall": "cd ios && pod install && cd .."` from your `package.json`. Because the error is an ios error not an android error.

Comment: Expo could be the problem, because of Native Modules. So I would try the React Native CLI. If that doesn't work I recommend looking through these issues https://github.com/davidohayon669/react-native-youtube/issues?q=requireNativeComponent.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Thank You, I wanted to try what you said about removing this `"postinstall": "cd ios && pod install && cd .."` from the `package.json` but this is not there, Or do you mean I should add it?

Comment: I thought you were using the example project from https://github.com/davidohayon669. If `postinstall` is not there you can ignore what I said.

Answer (score 0):

Such error **may occur** when package installation is not done properly.
Confirm if you install package in your app folder properly by checking

One more thing, **for Android user,**: The Android implementation of this component needs to have YouTube app installed on the device. Otherwise an error event will be triggered with `SERVICE_MISSING/SERVICE_DISABLED.`